# List the employees who are earning greater than or equal to the average amount of salary earned by employees belonging to the same department

Tags: postgresql

SELECT Fname, Lname, Salary,Dname

FROM EMPLOYEE,DEPARTMENT

WHERE Salary  >=

(SELECT AVG(Salary)

FROM EMPLOYEE );

GROUP BY dname

Db fiddle link:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It keeps on showing syntax error near WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Salary, Dname
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E1
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT AS D ON Dnumber = Dno
WHERE Salary >= (SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM EMPLOYEE AS E2 WHERE E2.Dno = E1.Dno)
ORDER BY Dname, Fname, Lname
```

[image]

Comment: Would you like to share your SQLfiddle with us?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH

Comment: Updated the query to reflect your column names